# why delegate must be static?

Tags: c#, delegates, initializer, method-group

In code below I must declare method `MdrResponseInterpreter` `static` otherwise I have compilation error.

```
class.... {

    private StandardBuilder _mdrResponseBuilder = 
      new StandardBuilder(MdrResponseInterpreter);

    public static bool MdrResponseInterpreter(DNMessageDeliverer builder, 
                                              DNFieldSet message)
    {
        // .... work
    }
```

Why? As `_mdrResponseBuilder` is not static I expect that `MdrResponseInterpreter` should be able to access `this`

Answer (score 11):

Because field initializers don't have access to `this` / instance members. Move the initialization to the constructor if you want access to instance members.

The spec says:

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference `this` in a variable initializer

While your code doesn't explicitly reference `this`, the method group to delegate conversion does reference `this` implicitly if the method is an instance member.

Answer (score 5):

To add to CodeInChaos's answer (which is correct) you can just move the assignment to the constructor:

```
private StandartBuilder _mdrResponsBuilder;

public Foo() // Whatever your type is called
{
    // Simpler syntax for creating a delegate, too. Just use a
    // method group conversion...
    _mdrResponsBuilder = MdrResponseInterpreter;
}
```

EDIT: The above assumes that `StandartBuilder` is a delegate type. If it's a type with a constructor *accepting* a delegate type, then you'll need to go back to `new StandartBuilder(MdrResponseInterpreter)`, but still have it in the constructor.

Comment: Just wondering, how is that "_mdrResponsBuilder = MdrResponseInterpreter" is correct? Nothing in the question indicates that StandardBuilder is a delegate... It could be a class accepting a Func<DNMessageDeliverer, DNFieldSet, bool> in its constructor? Btw, I didn't downvote

Comment: @odalet: Yes, that's possible. I think it's more likely (given the question title) that it's a delegate type. Will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use instance members in initializers.

Think of a delegate as having 1) An object reference and 2) A method reference. Since you cannot access `this`, there is no way to set the object reference, so the only way to be able to use the method as a delegate is to declare it as `static` (because a delegate's object reference is `null` for static methods). Moving your initialization to the constructor can help you get around this.

Comment: There definitely *is* an object at that point (otherwise where is the value being assigned?) but you're not allowed to access `this` yet.

Comment: I'd still say it's unclear. The object *does* exist, fully. It may not have been fully *initialized*, but that's true in the constructor body too. (There may be other derived constructor bodies which have yet to run, too...)

Answer (score 1):

The method has to be static because it is invoked at object initialization, before the constructor has started executing. If you want to access `this`, call the initialization method from inside your constructor.